# Regular expression that matches a string only if it contains non-word characters

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression that matches a one word string only if it contains non word characters (\W+). If there is at least one word character it shouldn't match. White spaces are guaranteed to not exist in the string.

```
Valid examples:
$
&
@!

Invalid examples:
yahoo!
i@world.com
```

The `/\W/+` is not doing what i want, it validates the above examples.
The language I am working is PHP in case this matters.
Test it here https://regex101.com/r/766z4j/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add anchors at the begining and at the end:

```
/^\W+$/
```

In PHP:

```
if (preg_match('/^\W+$/', $string)) {
    echo "Match\n";
}
```

You could also test the negation:

```
if ( ! preg_match('/\w/', $string)) {
    echo "Match\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! In the end it was that simple

Comment: Thanks for adding the example as well but I knew this part already.